# How to add a message to next if statement in ruby

Tags: ruby

How to combine `next` with `puts "#{web_url.status[0].to_i}` together and display it in console but  only if `if` part is true.

```
tried:
next if ... && puts "{web_url.status[0].to_i}"



  web_url  = open(url, :proxy => BaseParser::PROXY, "User-Agent" => BaseParser.rand_ua_string() )

  next if web_url.nil?
  next if web_url.status[0].to_i == 410
  next if web_url.status[0].to_i == 310
  next if web_url.status[0].to_i == 404
  next if web_url.status[0].to_i == 530
```

Comment: Why not just `if...; puts...; <possibly other statements>; next; end` (or put these statements on separate lines and eliminate semicolons)?  Note there are many ways to combine your last four statements, such as `next if %w[410 310 404 530].include?(web_url.status[0])` or `case web_url.status[0].to_i; when 410, 310, 404, 530; next; when ...; end`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I will choose `next if %w[410 310 404 530].include?(web_url.status[0])`. It is more idiomatic to me :) I could add this to my answer. But I didn't as I think OP's problem was how to print messages while using `next` keyword.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here it is :

```
next puts "#{web_url.status[0].to_i}" if x == 2 # expression here
```

Example :

```
x = 1
until x > 3
  next puts("#{x} matched"),x+=1 if x == 2
  puts "this iteration has number #{x}"
  x += 1
end
# >> this iteration has number 1
# >> 2 matched
# >> this iteration has number 3
```

Go through the documentation [**keywords**](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/).